# most simple streamlined way of writing to public shared 'txt' file?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I wish to have a *.txt file hosted somewhere very publicly on the web.
I have a text input box and button on my app, and when the button is pressed I want to simply append to the text file with a newline char.
When the app is opened I want to read in this public *.txt file

I can do very cool stuff with this using Java, I just need to know the best way to host this *.txt file and write to it..

the simplest solution I can think of is to have a whole bleeping LAMP stack on a cloud server, and have a *.php file that uses GET method to append the text to a text file on the server.  (the button will just go to url with textbox text appended to url) But do I really need to set up a whole cloud server just to append text to a public text file??

the solution i'm thinking of right now:

1. set up PHP server (for example http://sharedtextbox.com/appendtxt.php)
2. have a php file that takes txt from variable in URL and appends it to txt file hosted on server
3. suppose text "michealJackson" is entered in box, when button on my app is pressed, it redirects to URL  http://sharedtextbox.com/appendtxt.php?value=michealJackson
4. appendtxt.php does something like myFile.write(GET['value'] . '\n');

but do i really need to set up a whole cPanel linux vm php server just to append text to a publicly hosted *.txt file?

to reiterate, I'm looking for clues on how to do this:

1. have publicly hosted *.txt file somewhere (is there a good free place to host this? )
2. there is textbox and button on my app, when button is presed, text in textbox is appended to public file

i just know how to code haha i have no idea what the simplest way to do this is, i'm about to give up and just use google cloud to host a whole vm just for this but there must be a simpler method??

other methods i've considered and rejected cuz too complex:

1. use cloud mysql database (i don't need a whole database with tables and stuff tho, just one file)
2. use google sheets somehow
3. use leaderboards https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/leaderboards (idk if this is more or less complicated than just setting up php server)
4. user SMTP emailing to email the text to my email and then i manually upload the text to the publicly hosted txt file

EDIT:
upon doing reserach i found out i can use https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/06/tutorial-adding-cloud-backend-to-your-application-with-android-studio_26.html google cloud backend to do this, i am going to run with this for now, please let me know if you know a simpler way

Comment: upon doing reserach i found out i can use https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/06/tutorial-adding-cloud-backend-to-your-application-with-android-studio_26.html google cloud backend to do this, i am going to run with this for now, please let me know if you know a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

I think it's also possible that for you to host the .txt file in google cloud storage. And have some simple cloud function that get/modify the .txt file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).